# Mobile App tile based with centered view scrolling in all directions

Tags: javascript, android, unity-game-engine, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I try to program the following (mobile app) and would really appreciate your input on how to start:

−   Scenario 1: Web-App using MEAN stack, ionic framework and additional plugins for a later deployment on all mobile platforms.

−   Scenario 2: Native Android App

−   Scenario 3: Unity3D App

−   The users view should be centred in the middle of a larger so called ‚arena‘, the boundaries of the arena are initially set. The user should be able to move (finger gesture) the view in all directions to move around in the defined arena. If the arena boundaries increase, the view should still be centred initially but scrolling around would simply take longer.

−   The arena contains tiles which are clickable and e.g. have a certain, varying color from tile to tile. All tiles are positioned next to each other. In a scenario where too many tiles exist, the overflow can only be viewed by moving the view around in the arena (see forth bullet point).

−   All is 2-D based.

Unity3D is most certainly the most easy way to go but looks like overkill to me. I don’t know how to realise this in Android and doubt that this is even possible within a browser without the use of extensive plugins which might be difficult to fully adjust to my needs.

I hope somebody has an idea and can help me out. Please find my concept art below!

[Concept Art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwLBo.jpg)